Customise order confirmation message
I'm working on a Drupal 10 offsite payment module wherein I'm trying to customise order confirmation message with custom message along with payment information such as transaction id, merchant ref number etc. I've tried using EventSubscriber, but for some reason I can't see any change in the confirmation message. I don't understand why it's not working. I cleared Drupal cache too.
Have a look at my code:
Path - modules/my_module/src/EventSubscriber/OrderCompletionSubscriber.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Event\CheckoutCompleteEvent;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Event\CheckoutEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface;

/**
 * Event subscriber to customize the order completion message.
 */
class OrderCompletionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * The messenger service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface
   */
  protected $messenger;

  /**
   * Constructs a new OrderCompletionSubscriber.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface $messenger
   *   The messenger service.
   */
  public function __construct(MessengerInterface $messenger) {
    $this->messenger = $messenger;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[CheckoutEvents::CHECKOUT_COMPLETE][] = ['onCheckoutComplete', 100];
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * Alters the order completion message.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\commerce_checkout\Event\CheckoutCompleteEvent $event
   *   The checkout complete event.
   */
  public function onCheckoutComplete(CheckoutCompleteEvent $event) {
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    
    // Get order related information from the gateway response.
    $merchant_ref_number = $order->getData('merchant_ref_number');
    $transaction_id = $order->getData('transaction_id'); 
    $status = $order->getData('status');

    // Build custom success or failure message based on the status code.
    if ($status == '00') {
      $message = $this->t('Your order has been successfully completed. Merchant Ref Number: @merchant_ref_number, Transaction ID: @transaction_id', [
        '@merchant_ref_number' => $merchant_ref_number,
        '@transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
      ]);
    }
    elseif ($status == '05') {
      $message = $this->t('Your order could not be completed. Please try again. Merchant Ref Number: @merchant_ref_number, Transaction ID: @transaction_id', [
        '@merchant_ref_number' => $merchant_ref_number,
        '@transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
      ]);
    }
    else {
      // Handle other statuses if necessary.
      $message = $this->t('There was an issue processing your order. Please contact support. Merchant Ref Number: @merchant_ref_number, Transaction ID: @transaction_id', [
        '@merchant_ref_number' => $merchant_ref_number,
        '@transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
      ]);
    }

    $this->messenger->addMessage($message);
  }

}


Path - modules/my_module/my_module.services.yml:
services:
  my_module.order_completion_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber\OrderCompletionSubscriber
    arguments: ['@messenger']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }


I just see an error in log report - "Error: Undefined constant Drupal\commerce_checkout\Event\CheckoutEvents::CHECKOUT_COMPLETE"
Can anyone please guide me in this? How can I achieve this? Any alternate simple way of doing this? My simple requirement is I need to display custom order completion message for successful order completion (when user redirects back to site from gateway) and for declined orders too. And for successful orders I need to customise confirmation emails (if possible).
Click link to see screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/NXPUbRxEbqhp
Update: I genuinely need help to resolve this issue asap. So Whoever helps me will get paid with bounty. Please guys!! Help.

Is orderCompleteHandler correct? Thats not in your code snippet

Please check, I've updated the code. Thanks for response.
